# Paley Wiener Theorem on sinc function

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, signal-processing

Use the Paley-Wiener theorem to argue that, although ${\rm sinc}\left(t\right)$ is bandlimited, ${\rm sinc}\left(t^{3}\right)$ is not.  Explain how the above result allows reconstruction of some non-bandlimited signals from nonuniformly-spaced samples.

**My Attempt**
I know that using the Paley Wiener Theorem that
\begin{equation}
{\rm sinc}\left(t\right) = \frac{\sin\left(t\right)}{t}= \frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}{\rm e}^{{\rm i}xt}\,{\rm d}t 
\end{equation}
and that
\begin{equation}
\left\vert\frac{\sin\left(t\right)}{t}\right\vert \leq Ce^{\left\vert t\right\vert}
\end{equation}
I found this result on another question but am not exactly sure how it was derived or how I would apply it to ${\rm sinc}\left(t^{3}\right)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hint about using the Paley-Wiener theorem is intended for the part about $\operatorname{sinc} (t^3)$. You did not need it for $\operatorname{sinc} t$. Indeed, the compactly supported transform is exhibited explicitly, and the exponential bound follows directly from $$|\sin z| \le \frac12( |e^{iz}|+|e^{-iz}|) \le e^{|z|}$$
(The denominator $t$ only makes this smaller when $t$ is large, but at any rate polynomial terms are negligible here.)

But once we plug a higher power of $t$ into  $\operatorname{sinc} $, the exponential type is lost. For $y>0$ we have 
$$  |\operatorname{sinc} ((iy)^3) | \ge \frac{1}{2 y ^3} (e^{i(iy)^3}-e^{-i(iy)^3})
 =  \frac{1}{2 y ^3} (e^{y^3}-e^{-y^3})
$$ 
Clearly, this grows faster than $e^{Cy}$ for any $y$. The [Paley-Wiener theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem) (compact case) implies that this function does not have compactly supported Fourier transform.